# are network requests due to code after a service worker is registered guaranteed to be served by the service worker fetch() handler?

Tags: service-worker

[Registering](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers#register_a_service_worker) a service worker is done in index.html with (eg):

```
<script>
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
    // Registration was successful
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
  }, function(err) {
    // registration failed :(
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
  });
</script>
```

If that code is followed by something that requests a resource, eg:

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
```

is that request guaranteed to trigger the 'fetch' event handler in the service worker (and so, potentially, be served from a cache)?

Or, should any code that causes a network access in index.html be added dynamically in the then() callback of the register() function (and, is THAT then guaranteed to be served by the service worker's 'fetch' event handler)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading through "[The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle)" for more general information.

The answer to most of your questions is "no," since what you're talking about is the initial registration of the service worker. Registering a service worker kicks off an installation and activation process that's independent from the promise returned by `register()`. The only thing you could infer from that promise is whether *starting* the process succeeded or not.

What you're asking about—whether a `fetch` handler will be invoked or not—relies on a service worker being in **control** of the current page.

In terms of JavaScript, if you want to answer the question "is this page controlled by (any) service worker?", you can do that by checking whether or not `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is `undefined`.

If you want to write code that will only execute once there's a service worker in control of the current page (with the caveat that it might *never* execute, if something prevented the service worker from properly activating), you could do that by [creating a promise](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/799#issuecomment-165499718) that will resolve immediately if there's already a controller, and will otherwise resolve once the [`controllerchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/oncontrollerchange) event fires:

```js
const p = new Promise(r => {
  if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) return r();
  navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', e => r());
});

// Later, if you want code to execute only if the page is controlled:
p.then(() => {
  // There's a SW in control at this point.
});
```

Inside your service worker, you can [add the following](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#clientsclaim) to your `activate` handler to ensure that as soon as a newly installed service worker activates, it takes control of any open pages (including the page that registered it for the first time):

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', () => self.clients.claim());
```

If you *don't* include `self.clients.claim()` inside your service worker's `activate` handler, then the page that starts out uncontrolled will never start being controlled, even though it's registered a service worker that has activated.